# StringFormat on Binding

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, string-formatting, date-formatting

View:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Date}"/>
```

I want to format the Date to "dd/MM/yyyy", in other words, without the time.

I tried it: `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}}"/>`, but it doesn't work.

Gives me an error: The property 'StringFormat' was not found in type 'Binding'.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The best and the easiest way would be to use a converter to which you pass the Date and get the formatted string back. In e.g. `MyNamespace.Converters` namespace:

```
public class DateFormatConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;

        DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(value.ToString());
        return dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

And in your xaml just reference the converter and add the following converter:

```
xmlns:conv="using:MyNamespace.Converters"
```

in your xaml page and in page.resources add this

```
<conv:DateFormatConverter x:Name="DateToStringFormatConverter"/>

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Date, Converter={StaticResource DateToStringFormatConverter}"/>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Error: The resource "DateStringToFormatConverter" could not be resolved.

Comment: You have to declare the converter in your xaml to use it

Comment: If you could edit your answer to a complete answer, would be great.

Comment: Use the parameter to pass the format string and this does the job. I wonder why they didn't implement StringFormat in UWP?

Answer (score 8):

I know this is late but I had the same question and came up with this solution. Maybe not the shortest but pure XAML.

```
    <TextBlock>
        <Run Text="{x:Bind Foo.StartDate.Day}"/>.<Run Text="{x:Bind Foo.StartDate.Month}"/>.<Run Text="{x:Bind Foo.StartDate.Year}"/>
    </TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 7):

There is no property named `StringFormat` in [Binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.binding.aspx) class. You can use [Converter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.binding.converter.aspx) and [ConverterParameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.binding.converterparameter.aspx) to do this. You can refer to [Formatting or converting data values for display](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-quickstart#formatting-or-converting-data-values-for-display).

For example here, I bind the date of a `DatePicker` to the text of a `TextBlock`.

XAML:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:DateFormatter x:Key="DateConverter"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <DatePicker Name="ConverterParmeterCalendarViewDayItem"></DatePicker>
    <TextBlock Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="{Binding ElementName=ConverterParmeterCalendarViewDayItem, Path=Date, Converter={StaticResource DateConverter},ConverterParameter=\{0:dd/MM/yyyy\}}" />
</Grid>
```

code behind, the DateFormatter class:

```cs
public class DateFormatter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var a = language;
        // Retrieve the format string and use it to format the value.
        string formatString = parameter as string;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(formatString))
        {
            return string.Format(formatString, value);
        }

        return value.ToString();
    }

    // No need to implement converting back on a one-way binding
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Came to give exactly the same answer. The best way it can be done is with a converter, as shown above, unless you change the Date to a string in code-behind and format it there instead.

[Info on DateTime formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately, it isn't working here..The type 'local:DateFormatter' was not found. What am I missing?

Comment: You need to create a class named DateFormatter, please see my `DateFormatter` class.

Comment: @developer033 Ok, please see my shared sample [StringFormatInBinding](http://1drv.ms/1P57M1N).

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT I downloaded your project and put everything equal to its... Same error: "The type 'local:DateFormatter' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.".

Comment: ....Did you delete this `xmlns:local="using:'your project'"`? If not, there is some problem with the xaml designer, it may be tagged as a error, but you can still run this project and it should work fine.

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT - Your OneDrive link doesn't work any more. Could you update it?

Comment: If XAML complains about not finding reference to your DateFormatter, make sure the xmls:local variable points to the right namespace. You can always make a new xmls reference called whatever you like to point to a specific file.

Comment: This is for the `Windows.UI.Xaml.Data` namespace. For the `IValueConverter` in `System.Windows.Data` the method signature on Convert and ConvertBack changes the `string language` parameter to `CultureInfo culture`.

Answer (score 6):

Since 14393, you can use [functions in x:Bind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/function-bindings).

This means you can format your date like:

```
Text="{x:Bind sys:String.Format('{0:dd/MM/yyyy}', ViewModel.Date)}"
```

Just ensure you have included a reference to the System namespace:

```
<Page 
     xmlns:sys="using:System"
     ...
```

Answer (score 4):

why to complicate? You can use compiled data binding

```
{x:Bind ViewModel.PropertyWithDateTime.ToString("....")}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent example here:

[Example from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br209826)

if your converter class is in a different namespace (as suggested to be in a separate folder) you can add

```
xmlns:conv="using:MyNamespace.Converters"
```

and use it like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  <conv:DateToStringConverter x:Key="Converter1"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

the rest should stay the same as in the example from the link.

Answer (score 0):

The nice thing about `StringFormat` is that it allows you to specify the format of the output. Here is a converter I use that allows you to specify the format.

```
public sealed class DateTimeToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FormatProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Format), typeof(bool), typeof(DateTimeToStringConverter), new PropertyMetadata("G"));

    public string Format { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value is DateTime dateTime && value != null)
        {
            return dateTime.ToString(Format);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return DateTime.ParseExact(value.ToString(), Format, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    }
}
```

How to use (example with multiple formats):

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <converters:DateTimeToStringConverter 
            x:Name="dateStringConverter" 
            Format="dd-MM-yyyy" />
        <converters:DateTimeToStringConverter
            x:Name="timeStringConverter"
            Format="HH:mm" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>

<!-- Display the date -->
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Date, Converter={StaticResource dateStringConverter}}" />    

<!-- Display the time -->
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Date, Converter={StaticResource timeStringConverter}}" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
<Label x:Name="LblEstEndTime" Text="{Binding EndTime, StringFormat='Est. End Time: {0:MM/dd/yy h:mm tt}'}" Style="{StaticResource ListCellSubTitleStyle}" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" />
```

---

Comment: Whilst code only answers may solve the original problem, some explanation would help a lot in understanding the method you've used and how it works.

Comment: this is not a UWP solution

Answer (score -1):

You can do this in xml itself. Here...

```
<DatePicker 
SelectedDate="{Binding Date, Mode=TwoWay}" 
Text="{Binding ., StringFormat='dd/MM/yyyy'}"/>
```

Comment: `StringFormat` does not exist in UWP's `Binding` class.
Furthermore, XML is not the same as XAML. XAML is an XML-based technology, but XAML and XML are not interchangeable terms.