# Format TimeSpan in Xaml (UWP)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, string-formatting, timespan

How do you format a `TimeSpan` in XAML with a custom format? I want hour and minutes.

Based on the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings), the way to do this in C# seems like it should be:

```
interval.ToString(@"h\:mm");
```

I want to be able to format the `TimeSpan` in XAML, however, from within a binding. [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34713126/stringformat-on-binding) seems viable, but I wanted to create a general converter, that I could pass a format string into. My converter is as follows:

```
public class TimeSpanFormatConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        string result = "";
        if (value == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (parameter == null)
        {
            return value;
        }

        if (value is TimeSpan timeSpan)
        {
            try
            {
                result = timeSpan.ToString((string)parameter);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                result = "";
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In theory, I could use this converter as follows:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <converters:TimeSpanFormatConverter x:key="TimeSpanConverter"></converters:TimeSpanFormatConverter>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
    <!-- Some properties omitted for brevity. -->
    <ListView>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:MyModel">
                <Grid>

                    <!-- PROBLEM IS HERE -->
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Interval, Converter={StaticResource TimeSpanConverter}, ConverterParameter='h\:mm'}"></TextBlock>

                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Note here that 'MyModel' has a property called 'Interval' that is of type 'TimeSpan'.

This does not work, however, because I need the backslash. The XAML parsing removes the backslash, thus passing in "h:mm" to the converter (which I verified through the debugger).

It also does not like two backslashes, as that throws a compiler error from the generated .g.cs file, saying "\:" is an "unrecognized escape sequence".

No variations of encoding the back slash have worked. I have tried:

```
h:mm
h\:mm
h\\:mm
h\\\:mm
h&#92;:mm
h&#92;\:mm
h&#92;&#92;:mm
h&#92;&#92;&#58;mm
```

What is the magic string of letters that need to be put into the `ConverterParameter`?

As an alternative, the MultiBinding solution explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563081/how-to-format-timespan-in-xaml/33278055#33278055) looked promising, but according to Visual Studio, MultiBinding is not supported in UWP.

Comment: You don't need to escape `:`. What does it say when you try putting in `h:mm`?

Comment: BTW, I would create a custom control for this. Say, `<local:Time Text="{x:Bind Interval}" Format="h:mm" />`. Much cleaner.

Comment: Putting in `h:mm` results in the line `result = timeSpan.ToString((string)parameter);` throwing a "Input string was not in a correct format." exception.

Comment: Why did you try `&#92;` and not `&#58;`? Can you try this exactly: `h&#58;mm` -- just learned that TimeSpan doesn't have the same format method as DateTime. Looking for the correct format string now.

Comment: Just tried that. That still results in "h:mm" going into the converter, which results in the same "Input string was not in a correct format" exception thrown that that same line. Maybe the backslash is tied to the "@" symbol with the string? Not sure. I know that `result = timespan.ToString(@"h\:mm");` gives me the result I want. I just need to figure out how to encode that in the XAML.

Comment: Yeah for that you'd need to put `\\ ` in the XAML. And that would look ugly, so maybe put `h mm` in XAML and replace spaces with `:` in code; that could work. But I think you should instead create a custom control for this.

Comment: What I mean is the answer to this question will be ugly. If you're going to use this in multiple places, you should create a custom control. If not, I'm gonna try and find the solution now.

Comment: I can only try in WPF and `h\\:mm` and `h\\\:m` worked for me. I can suggest creating a static list of `MyModel`s somewhere and initialize it with a few sample values, then set `ItemsSource` to it so it's design-time. Then you can just change the ConverterParameter and see the changes in the Designer immediately.

Answer (score 0):

> because I need the backslash. The XAML parsing removes the backslash, thus passing in "h:mm" to the converter (which I verified through the debugger).

Yep, it is correct, The `ConverterParameter` is object but not string, This may cause the backslash to be removed when xaml parses. I think you could create `StringFormat` property for your `TimeSpanFormatConverter` and pass the `Format` when `Converter` initialize.

```
public class TimeSpanFormatConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public string StringFormat { get; set; }
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        string result = "";
        if (value == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (parameter == null)
        {
            return value;
        }

        if (value is TimeSpan timeSpan)
        {
            try
            {
                result = timeSpan.ToString(StringFormat);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                result = "";
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:TimeSpanFormatConverter x:Key="TimeSpanConverter" StringFormat="h\:mm"/>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{x:Bind Interval, Converter={StaticResource TimeSpanConverter},Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```